# Outlook 365 Fill

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, imap

I got a new PC, and wanted to transfer my email folders there. I went to my old PC that has Outlook, and then I exported my email folders into 3 .PST files. I don't know why it had to go into 3 separate files, I would have preferred doing 1. Anyway, then on the new PC, I imported the folders into Outlook 365, and there they were. Before importing, I setup everything on the PC, did all updates, signed into Win11 with MS account, signed into Outlook 365 with MS Account. This is Comcast email, and on Comcast's website, they implied that it was set to IMAP.

When I go to write someone a new email, it has 2-3 contact lists to choose from, and none of the contacts autofill in the To textbox. I must manually select the recipients. After sending an email to a person, it will then autofill their name in the next email. I have 500 contacts, how can I make them all autofill without sending them an email first?

Comment: If you had your accounts configured as IMAP then it was unnecessary to backup your emails to a local .PST archive. Contacts are separate it sounds like you haven’t exported your contacts from Outlook. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-contacts-from-outlook-10f09abd-643c-4495-bb80-543714eca73f) are those instructions

Comment: I think the folders I manually transferred were not directly a part of the comcast email account, I think they were saved in a separate section, only on the old computer.

I have done Outlook import/export before with CSV files. I am not confused about your response, but I want to make sure we are on the same page, do you understand that I already have all my contacts inside of the new Outlook?

Comment: If you have already exported and imported your contact list, that was not explicitly stated in your question, your question only mentions the "folders" which I took as you archived emails into individual .PST files.  I don't believe there is a way to transfer the list of contacts that will automatically be suggested unless you are using Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make them all autofill without sending them an email first?

What do you mean about "autofill"? Do you mean [autocomplete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/information-about-the-outlook-autocomplete-list)?

If so, it's suggested that you could copy and import AutoComplete list to the new computer, as mentioned in the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/information-about-the-outlook-autocomplete-list#how-to-enable-the-autocomplete-feature). And remember to enable the AutoComplete feature in new computer.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.